# Android Push Notification with Azure Notification Hub

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to implement Push notifications into my Android app using the Azure Notifications Hub.  I have followed the instructions [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-android-get-started/) but when I get to the step for `Adding Azure Notification Hubs libraries` I am getting stuck.  First off, there is no file at the Files tab on the link they provide that is named `notification-hubs-0.4.jar` so I assume the one I want is `notification-hubs-android-sdk-0.4.jar`.  So I downloaded it and included it in my assets\libs folder.  I then followed the instructions and added the required lines to my build.gradle file but I keep getting an error stating

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources' Process 'command 'C:\pathtothefile...\aapt.exe'' finished with a non-zero exit value 1.

My build.gradle file looks like this...

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapplicationid.android"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1@aar'
    compile files('src/main/assets/libs/android-maps-extensions.jar')
    compile files('src/main/assets/libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK"
    }
}
```

Am I doing something completely wrong here?  Could someone please point out my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we will update the documentation properly as well, but as we do so, add compile 'com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:0.4@aar' into dependencies and see if that works.

Comment: Actually, what ended up working is I upgrade everything I could within Android Studio and restarted.  Then the project would build successfully.  Now I'm getting an error on run though showing 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult.isSuccess()' on a null object reference'

Comment: Did this ever get resolved on your side? We tried to repro following the tutorial but it worked fine... do you have the complete error trace?

Comment: @I went through and updated everything I could think of in Android Studio, and after doing that and restarting the errors went away.  Must have been related to an old SDK version or something.

Comment: Good to hear that things worked out! Let me know if you bump into any other issues.

Comment: What does "@aar" do? I did this for the authentication packages and it just magically worked?

Comment: @RyanDawkins I guess we'll never know